# VM arguments are added (automatically) after server start

Tags: java, tomcat7, ibm-rad

I'm facing a serious problem with my tomcat server, which I can't resolve by my own, so I'm hoping you guess can help me out.

**Setting**

IBM Rational Application Developer 8.5.1

Tomcat 7.0.32

**Problem**

When I'm deploying a WAR on the tomcat, a bunch of vm arguments is added automatically, which causes a "kickout" of my own vm arguments, because there's so many of the automatically added ones.

The arguments are:

```
"-agentpath:D:\Entwicklung\IBM\IBMShared\plugins\org.eclipse.tptp.platform.jvmti.
runtime_4.7.101.v201210191900\agent_files\win_ia32\JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:
server=standalone,file=;ProbekitAgent:ext-pk-BCILibraryName=BCIEngProbe,ext-pk-
probescript=D:\Entwicklung\workspaces\RAD\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.
llc.ide.core\.coverage\1361184798442-vke-core-persistency-jar-org.eclipse.jst.
server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType.probescript" "-Dcoverage.out.file=
D:\Entwicklung\workspaces\RAD\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.llc.ide.core
\.coverage\1361184798442-vke-core-persistency-jar-org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.
core.launchConfigurationType.coveragedata"  "-Xbootclasspath/a:D:\Entwicklung\
IBM\IBMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.llc.engine_1.1.1.v20121205_2240;
D:\Entwicklung\IBM\IBMShared\plugins\org.eclipse.hyades.execution_4.5.
103.v201210051900\hexl.jar;D:\Entwicklung\IBM\IBMShared\plugins\
org.eclipse.hyades.execution_4.5.103.v201210051900\hexr.jar" -Dcatalina.base
="D:\Entwicklung\workspaces\RAD\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.
server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Entwicklung\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\
apache-tomcat-7.0.32" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\Entwicklung\workspaces\
RAD\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst. server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Entwicklung\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\apache-tomcat-
7.0.32\endorsed" -Dcoverage.server.mode=true "-Dac.library.path=D:
\Entwicklung\IBM\IBMShared\plugins\org.eclipse.tptp.platform.
ac.win_ia32_4.5.1.v201210051900\agent_controller\bin"
```

**Things I tried to solve the problem**

- tomcat new installed
- RAD new installed (from scratch)
- tomcat cleaned and redeployed

I hope someone knows what's going on here, I'm just curious what and why is changing the vm arguments...
If you need further information, please let me know

Comment: so as soon as i start the tomcat and take a look at the vm arguments theres the posted set of arguments in the run config

Comment: It seems that many of those arguments are added by the IDE. Maybe you can disable some plugins, like the coverage. Another option is to use a clean Eclipse IDE for this particular project.

Comment: The IDE is a special package provided by the client (security reasons and stuff), therefore I'm not able to disable plugins or use a clean installation. I'm working on this project for over a year now and never faced such problems...it all started after a new installation of windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with RAD 8.5 and WAS 6.1 and in my case I had to edit the server.xml

It is located in : 
[WEBSPHERE_HOME]\AppServer\profiles\config\cells[NodeCellName]Node01Cell\nodes[NodeName]Node01\servers\server1\server.xml

Look for the tag: < jvmEntries /> 
This tag has few attributes like @debugArgs, @genericJvmArguments make sure that you have the arguments you need.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: To reply to your deleted comment: yes, I've worked on dozens of systems, many with 1-10m LOC. That's orthogonal to the notion that we must return nulls. My original statement still stands, and *I* haven't returned a null in ages--hopefully you haven't either, or you're just perpetuating an anti-pattern that's trivial to avoid.

Comment: @Dave - dude :) let go already. If you remember my comment is that when you work with existing systems and third party APIs we don't always have the liberty to change them and therefore you'd want to check for null before you use an object. Again - I will give you an example with java.util.Map - that is standard java utility and it does return null and like it or not your code should be able to handle it. Would you agree?